# On the Absolute Value of the Riemann Zeta Function on the Critical Line

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Is there any sort of (closed form preferably, though if not, it's fine) function for $|\zeta(\frac12+it)|$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function? Anything is welcome, so I can take it from there. Upper bounds, lower bounds and asymptotics  are also accepted.

Comment: How about the Riemann Siegel formula?

Comment: @zz7948 I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: @Dave related to approximating zeta. Good for numerical approximations and maybe the best we have to a ’closed form’ in some situations. Taking it with the ’anything is welcome’ attitude

Comment: @zz7948 Yeah, but that was for zeta, not for the absolute value of it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not known whether, for $t>0$ large, $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$ is smaller than $t^{1/7}$, while it is conjectured that $1/7$ can be replaced by any positive exponent. This should answer your question. For more information, consult Titchmarsh's book on the Riemann zeta function, there is a whole chapter on this topic. Another good starting point is the relevant [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_hypothesis).

Comment: Are there any unconditional results?

Comment: @QuoteDave: There are hundreds of papers on the subject. As a starter, read Titchmarsh's chapter and the Wikipedia entry (in my post). See also the recent work of Soundararajan, Harper etc. on the arXiv. This is one the hot topics of analytic number theory.

Comment: Though when they say "$c_{k,j}$ as some constant", what kind of constants are they talking about?

Comment: @QuoteDave: That asymptotic formula is only conjectured. As the Wikipedia page says, a conjectured formula for $c_{k,j}$ was given by Keating & Snaith (2000). The best unconditional upper bounds appear in the table in the Wikipedia page. Please study the literature. It is vast and easy to find.

Comment: No, I am really only interested in $k=1$, which has been proven, and the Wikipedia page never gave any values of $c$.

Comment: @QuoteDave: That conjectured bound is a moment bound (which implies pointwise bounds though, see Titchmarsh's book). Pointwise bounds of the form $|\zeta(1/2+it)|<c(1+|t|)^{1/6}$ were proven with explicit constants $c>0$. I don't have time to look up this part of the literature, just use Google, MathSciNet etc. I gave you pointers. At any rate, it is a more substantial question how the $1/6$ can be reduced, so analytic number theorists are mainly occupied with that. The current record is by Fields medalist Bourgain from 2017 as recorded in the Wikipedia page. Discussion is closed on my part.